# changing Visibility to hosted winForms element in wpf application

Tags: winforms, element, visibility, hosted

I have ReportViewer winForms control for showing Microsoft Reports in my WPF application hosted over WindowsFormsIntegration.
When the MouseDown event of my textBlock triggers, I would like it to fade lets say from 0 to 100 visability, like some other elements in my Window. It doesn't, so I was wondering is it the same for all hosted controls or this one specific and how can it be solved?

Regards,

Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WindowsFormsHost supports Transparency. But some WinForms Controls do not.

See the [Supported Scenarios in Windows Presentation Foundation and Windows Forms Interoperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797.aspx) article on MSDN. Especially the first row in the "Behaviour" table:

> Some Windows Forms controls do not
>   support transparency. For example, the
>   TextBox and ComboBox controls will not
>   be transparent when hosted by WPF.